# NRF24l01+ works only when touching its antenna

Tags: arduino-uno, spi, nrf24l01+

I have two simple NRF24l01+ (with range of 200m) and two NRF24l01+ with range of 1km.and two socket adapter.

[image: what I have] or [what I have](http://uupload.ir/files/b1w0_nrf.jpg)

and I have two good library with names **RF24** and **RF24-master** . problem is that I tried a lot of combinations and just one of them worked : two simple NRF24l01+ with their socket adapter and with **Getting started** example of **RF24-master** library and only when I touch the antenna of the NRF it can transmit the package and get response. whats the problem? thats with me or my modules have problem?
I've also readed the datasheet and wrote my own code for modules.but it just worked with 1km range NRF24l01+ and most of the packages have failed.

my own code for transmitter :

```
#include <SPI.h>

#define cePin 7
#define csnPin 8

//#define cePin D0
//#define csnPin D1

int data = 7;

void IRQ() {
  Serial.println("STATUS register from IRQ ISR :  ");
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x07);
  delay(10);
  Serial.println(SPI.transfer(0xff), BIN);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);

  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x08);
  delay(10);
  Serial.println(SPI.transfer(0xff), BIN);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);

  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x07 + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xff);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);
}


void NRF_transmitterBegin() {

  //reading
  /*digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
    SPI.transfer(0x00);
    delay(10);
    Serial.println(SPI.transfer(0xff), BIN);
    delay(10);
    digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);*/

  pinMode(cePin, OUTPUT);  //CE
  pinMode(csnPin, OUTPUT);  //CSN
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);
  digitalWrite(cePin, 0);

  SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0);
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV4);
  SPI.begin();
  delay(1000);


  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);   //flush TX_FIFO
  SPI.transfer(0xe1);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);


  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);   //flush RX_FIFO
  SPI.transfer(0xe2);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);


  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x07 + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xf0);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);


  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x00 + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0x0e);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);
  delay(10);


  /*digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
    SPI.transfer(0x11 + 0x20);
    delay(10);
    SPI.transfer(0x3f);
    delay(10);
    digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);*/


  //Down for DYNPL
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x1c + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0x01);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);


  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x1d + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0x04);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);
  //Up for DYNPL


  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x01 + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0x3f);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);


  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x02 + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0x03);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);


  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x03 + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0x03);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);


  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x04 + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xff);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);


  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x05 + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0x4c);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);


  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x06 + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0x06);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);


  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x0a + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xaa);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xaa);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xaa);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xaa);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xaa);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);


  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x10 + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xaa);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xaa);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xaa);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xaa);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xaa);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);


  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), IRQ, FALLING);
  delay(10);

}

void NRF_transmit(int whatIsData , float data , float hum) {    //hum is used just for temp&humidity
  /*
     byte 0 says what is our data:  1 -> data and humidity    2 -> movement   3 -> gas

     1(float) :   byte 1 -> integer part of temp  byte 2 -> fractional part of temp   byte 3 -> integer part of humidity    byte 4 -> fractional part of humidity    byte 5 -> %battery
     2(binary) :  byte 1 -> %battery
     3(float) :   byte 1 -> integer part of gas   byte 2 -> fractional part of gas    byte 3 -> %battery

     %battery feature is in progress ...
  */

  int byte0 = 0 , byte1 = 0 , byte2 = 0 , byte3 = 0 , byte4 = 0 , byte5 = 0;
  float buf = 0;

  byte0 = whatIsData;

  switch (whatIsData) {
    case 1: {

        byte1 = data;
        buf = data - byte1;
        byte2 = buf * 10;

        byte3 = hum;
        buf = hum - byte3;
        byte4 = buf * 10;

        break;
      }
    case 2: {

        break;
      }
    case 3: {

        byte1 = data;
        buf = data - byte1;
        byte2 = buf * 10;

        break;
      }
    default: {
        break;
      }
  }

  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0xe1);   //flush TX_FIFO empty
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);

  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0xa0);   //write on TX_FIFO
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(byte0);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(byte1);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(byte2);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(byte3);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(byte4);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(byte5);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);

  digitalWrite(cePin, 1);   //CE High
  delay(1);
  digitalWrite(cePin, 0);   //CE Low

}


void NRF_monitorRegisters() {

  for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
    SPI.transfer(i);
    delay(10);
    Serial.print(i , HEX);
    Serial.print(" -> ");
    Serial.println(SPI.transfer(0xff), BIN);
    delay(10);
    digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);
  }
  Serial.println("");

}


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);

  NRF_transmitterBegin();
  NRF_monitorRegisters();

}

void loop() {

  NRF_transmit(3 , 15.1 , 0);

  delay(1000);
}
```

and my code for receiver :

```
#include <SPI.h>

#define cePin 7
#define csnPin 8

//#define cePin D0
//#define csnPin D1

long int lastTime = 0;

void IRQ() {

  int whatIsData = 0;
  int byte1 = 0 , byte2 = 0 , byte3 = 0 , byte4 = 0 , byte5 = 0;
  float data = 0 , hum = 0 , buf = 0;

  /*Serial.println("STATUS register from IRQ ISR :  ");
    digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
    SPI.transfer(0x07);
    delay(10);
    Serial.println(SPI.transfer(0xff), BIN);
    delay(10);
    digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);*/

  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x61);
  delay(10);
  whatIsData = SPI.transfer(0xff);
  delay(10);
  byte1 = SPI.transfer(0xff);
  delay(10);
  byte2 = SPI.transfer(0xff);
  delay(10);
  byte3 = SPI.transfer(0xff);
  delay(10);
  byte4 = SPI.transfer(0xff);
  delay(10);
  byte5 = SPI.transfer(0xff);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);

  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);   //flush RX_FIFO
  SPI.transfer(0xe2);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);

  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x07 + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xf0);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);
  delay(10);


  switch (whatIsData) {
    case 1: {

        buf = byte2;
        data = byte1 + buf / 10;
        buf = byte4;
        hum = byte3 + buf / 10;

        Serial.print("Received data from DHT22 -> temp:");
        Serial.print(data);
        Serial.print("  humidity:");
        Serial.println(hum);

        break;
      }
    case 2: {

        Serial.println("Received data from PIR -> Move detected");

        break;
      }
    case 3: {

        buf = byte2;
        data = byte1 + buf / 10;

        Serial.print("Received data from gas sensor -> %gas:");
        Serial.println(data);

        break;
      }
    default: {

        Serial.println("a problem accured");

        break;
      }
  }

}

void NRF_receiverBegin() {

  //reading
  /*digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
    SPI.transfer(0x00);
    delay(10);
    Serial.println(SPI.transfer(0xff), BIN);
    delay(10);
    digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);*/

  pinMode(cePin, OUTPUT);  //CE
  pinMode(csnPin, OUTPUT);  //CSN
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);
  digitalWrite(cePin, 0);

  SPI.setBitOrder(MSBFIRST);
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0);
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV4);
  SPI.begin();
  delay(100);

  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);   //flush TX_FIFO
  SPI.transfer(0xe1);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);

  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);   //flush RX_FIFO
  SPI.transfer(0xe2);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);

  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x07 + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xf0);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);
  delay(10);

  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x00 + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0x0f);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);
  delay(10);

  /*digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
    SPI.transfer(0x11 + 0x20);
    delay(10);
    SPI.transfer(0x01);
    delay(10);
    digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);*/

  //Down for DYNPL
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x1c + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0x01);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);


  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x1d + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0x04);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);
  //Up for DYNPL


  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x01 + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0x3f);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);


  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x02 + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0x03);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);


  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x03 + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0x03);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);


  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x04 + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xff);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);


  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x05 + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0x4c);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);


  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x06 + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0x06);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);


  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x0a + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xaa);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xaa);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xaa);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xaa);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xaa);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);


  digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
  SPI.transfer(0x10 + 0x20);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xaa);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xaa);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xaa);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xaa);
  delay(10);
  SPI.transfer(0xaa);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);

}


void NRF_startListening() {

  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(2), IRQ, FALLING);

  digitalWrite(cePin, 1);   //CE High
  Serial.println("Listening started");

}


void NRF_monitorRegisters() {

  for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    digitalWrite(csnPin, 0);
    SPI.transfer(i);
    delay(10);
    Serial.print(i , HEX);
    Serial.print(" -> ");
    Serial.println(SPI.transfer(0xff), BIN);
    delay(10);
    digitalWrite(csnPin, 1);
  }
  Serial.println("");

}

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);

  NRF_receiverBegin();
  NRF_startListening();
  NRF_monitorRegisters();

}


void loop() {

  /*if (millis() - lastTime > 20000) {
    NRF_monitorRegisters();
    lastTime = millis();
  }*/

}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "tow" which appears multiple times in your question? See [tow](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tow). Do you mean "two" or "a"? I understand English may not be your first language, but your question is hard to understand.

Comment: thanx and sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: *just one of them worked* - what do you mean by "worked"? What range are you testing over? I've got a few of those and they work fine over 20m or so.

Comment: I mean sending package and getting response.they are close to each other but I don't know why they can't communicate. I wrote my own code base on datasheet and now I'm adding it to my post.if U can pls try my code and let me know if it works.

Comment: If they are to close the signal will distort and data will be lost. For very short range communication you have to reduce the gain, which is what your hand does.

Comment: Sometimes I heard it's better to have some minimum distance of 20-30 cm... I tried the simple ones and got on fast speeds about 5-6 meters. Try also rotating them and not have other electronics/metal nearby.

Comment: thanx all.  
yeah , when I set PA to Low it works good. But still I can't understand why it doesn't work with 1km NRF or without socket adapter.
I thought it's a perfect module for RF communication but I have alot problem with that.

Comment: Those 1km versions have an additional amplifier. So at very short distances, they receive so much signal, they can't understand it. It's like someone shouting in a megaphone next to your ear, and all you can hear is ringing.

Comment: thanx Gerben. so I'm gonna try 1km modules far away from each other in next few days.I hope it work

Comment: The socket adapters take 5.0v. How much power are you supplying? 3.3 or 5v?

Comment: I give it a 5v from arduino and it works well about 95% of the time. but when I give it a 3.3v without socket it doesn't work! and I'm not familiar to stackoverflow so can u pls tell me how I can select a comment as 'useful comment' or it needs a high reputation?